# context free grammar that describes even numbers

Tags: automata

I am learning about context-free grammars and as a toy example I wanted to design one that describes binary digits ending with 0.

My attempt : S -> 1S | 0S | e0 - where e is the empty string. Is this correct?

Comment: Your language is regular, so a [regular grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) will suffice.

Comment: That looks okay. It is also possible to write a regular (or context-free) grammar for binary numerals that are multiples of **3**; you may enjoy trying to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're attempt seems fine. Try also to write it down formally, so that it is a direct application of the definition.

I would just omit the empty string, since $e0=0$. The way you write it just makes it harder to read and understand.